# How can I install angular version 1.1.5 via npm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm

I've tried:

```
npm install angular@1.1.5
```

But it give me an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: version not found: 1.1.5 : angular/1.1.5
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [bower](http://bower.io/) for the job (and git)!

Install it via npm

```
npm install -g bower
```

And then

```
bower install angular-unstable#1.1.5
```

It'll create a components directory with angular 1.1.5 inside.

You can install [3000+ components](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/) with bower.

Comment: Just to clarify npm and bower do the same things so just choose one

Answer (score 24):

Angular js is also available with npm. Just write the following line in your terminal.

```
 npm install angular
```

above command will install latest version of angular which is by default and for different version of the angular package use

```
npm install angular@1.1.5
```

This will install angular js via npm only.

**Note: Make sure you have npm installed in your operating system.**
[Download Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like angular itself is available from npm. https://npmjs.org/search?q=angular

There is a package for installing node + angular but it looks like it has 1.0.1 of angular in it. Here is the github associated with that package.

https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/node-angular/tree/master/lib/node-angular

Answer (score 0):

Update: angular does available from npm now.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular

just newbies should know...