# Npm install angular, unmet dependencies

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am really confused as to why this is happening, can anyone shed some light?

npm -v gives me version 2.13.5

This happens when i run

```
npm install angular


npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/browserify requires glob@'^4.0.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.14
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins requires findup-sync@'^0.2.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/findup-sync,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-phpspec requires gulp-util@'~2.2.14' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-util,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.6
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-phpunit requires gulp-util@'~2.2.14' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-util,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.6
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-rev-replace requires gulp-util@'~2.2.14' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-util,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.6
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream requires through2@'^0.6.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/arthurrafal/Desktop/bookSwapon/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0
angular@1.4.4 ../node_modules/angular
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808346/how-can-i-install-angular-version-1-1-5-via-npm)

Comment: How does your `package.json` look like? Do you get the same messages in a new folder that's just initialized with `npm init`? There is a similar [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies). The other mentioned question/answer is not up-to-date. Because I'm also installing angular with npm with-out any problems.

Comment: @AWolf The stack overflow link you provided didn't help, for some reason npm has unmet dependencies even when i try their solution, i was able to install angular through bower (using link firs commentor provided)but npm still has unmet dependencies,

Comment: Have you tried to remove `node _ modules` folder and re-install the dependencies with `npm install`? Do you get the same messages then?

Comment: Yes, tried that, still same message